# Two way binding not working?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I a  page which has code behind like

```
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public bool Executing
    {
        get
        {
            return _executing;
        }
        set
        {
            _executing = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Executing"));
            }

        }
    }

    public endpoints()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Executing = false;
        DataContext = this;

    }

   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         Executing=true;
        var accessPoints = wifi.GetAccessPoints();
         Executing=false;

        lvAccessPoints.ItemsSource = accessPoints.Select(ap => new WifiAccess
        {
            Executing=true;
            Points = ap,
            Password = string.Empty,
        }).ToList();


    }
```

and in my xaml

```
 <ProgressBar x:Name="progress" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Collapsed"></ProgressBar>
<MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Executing,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="progress" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
```

and at top i have

```
<Page.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVis" />
</Page.Resources>
```

But i was expecting the progress bar to hide at start and should show up when executing become true. But its showing all time.

an i have kept a text box like this

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Executing,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Padding="10,0" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

which always shows false, not changing

How can i fix this?

Comment: It is not clear what `Executing` property do you refer to in your binding: `Executing` of `WifiAccess` (in this case it is always `true` of course) or `Executing` of the entire page? Also you have a lot of strange code: 1) `MultiDataTrigger` with one condition should be replaced by `DataTrigger`; 2) `UpdateSourceTrigger` doesn't make sense for `Binding` in `DataTrigger`; 3) event raising should be done via variable or `?.Invoke`; 4) you completely ignore MVVM...

Answer (score 0):

The UI isn't updating because the UI thread is blocked during the execution of the Button Click handler.

You can make it work asynchronously like this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Executing = true;

    var accessPoints = await Task.Run(() => wifi.GetAccessPoints());

    Executing = false;
    ...
}
```

---

In order to make you Executing property setter thread-safe, you should write it like shown below, where the PropertyChanged event is accessed only once.

```
public bool Executing
{
    get { return _executing; }
    set
    {
        _executing = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Executing)));
    }
}
```

---

It's also pointless to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Executing Binding, because doing so has no effect. There also seems to be no need for a MultiDataTrigger. So you may use a simple DataTrigger like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Executing}" Value="True" />
```